# How do I make one Visual Studio project automatically execute before another?

Tags: visual-studio

I have two projects in my solution

- Client
- Server

Both compile to console applications.  When i execute the Client project by right clicking and selecting Debug...Start New Instance or by pressing F5, I would like it to automatically execute the server application.

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the solution, then click `Properties`. Use the `Startup Project` property page to set your configuration up. In your case I would select `Multiple startup projects` and sort them appropriately.